draw.io - Export SVG/PNG/JPEG showing deleted shapes
I draw some custom shapes on draw.io desktop. But when I exported them to SVG(I also tried to export it to PNG or JPEG), and then open the SVG file on Google Chrome, it shows some "deleted shapes". Very bizzare. As you can see, left is Chrome, right is draw.io desktop.
but when I export it to HTML and open the HTML on CHrome, it showing the correct shape.
enter image description here
I tried to copy the entire shapes to a new file, but same issue occurs. I also tried to open the file on different computer, same problem. It seems that there are some cache need to be cleaned on Draw.io

start deleting content from your SVG until you find the problematic parts

Dear Danny, I tried this way and found some custom shapes cause the same problem. I opened the exported SVG via Sketch, and found there are so many "Groups" in my SVG, which combines some "ghost shapes" and real shapes together. I don't know exactly why it happens, because on my Draw.io main page, I did not group those shapes.

When the browser displays the file correctly it sounds like you found a bug in Draw.io and other tools. Clean the file manually and continue work. Welcome in the world of programming.

thank you Danny. I decided to quit draw.io and use Sketch instead.
